# Was POSIX created because of Linux?

Tags: linux, posix, history

There are many versions of Linux systems. Is it because of Linux that POSIX was created?

Comment: The POSIX standards project was started in 1985; Linux in 1991.

Comment: Please merge this in to your existing question on POSIX.

Comment: edit your first question to ask this question as well, and delete this question. I'll post my response to my original answer.

Answer (score 4):

No. POSIX predates Linux. POSIX was created because there are many flavors of UNIX (AT&T, BSD, etc.), not Linux.